# By pressing a button i want to show the user all the data inserted to the boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Apostolh_Texnikou
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GN_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

> I want the user to click in the ready button and a window to pop out.
>   In the window the user must be able to copy the text.
>   I found how to make a pop window but its just a window which doesn't allow 
>   copy paste. thank you in advance

Comment: oh boy! every event is simply _barren_. What are you trying to achieve with these empty events?

Comment: What do you mean the only it does need coding is the ready button the rest are just like text boxes, and even the drop down menus can be eddied by the VS GUI. Not trying to learn code here mate just a simple question lel. I just dont know how to google it thats why i post it here.

Comment: This question seems like you want us to teach you how to program a windows application.  That is not the goal of this website.

Comment: We don't give examples, we help with specific issues. You seem to need a broader lesson here. Also, questions generally require *some* effort. Personally, I don't think a bunch of empty events count as actual effort.

Comment: You could be more helpful if you had just answered like Adam Kingsley below, but instead of helping you chose to be salty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into a more complex type of dialog box. Perhaps one with a textbox? This will require launching another form. (see [how to display textBox control in MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811859/how-to-display-textbox-control-in-messagebox))