# How do dismiss modal dialogue form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using code from this example: [Messagebox with input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797774/messagebox-with-input-field)

Once the user clicks the button on the form, nothing happens. The form remains. Do I need to wireup something for the modal to go away so I can get the textbox result?

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the form to close, you'll need to call `Close();` within the button clicked event on `Form2`.

Comment: I added that to the button click event. However, I don't fall into the conditional and never capture the textbox value.

Comment: Make sure the button clicked event also sets DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the `DialogResult` property of the `Button` itself in the winforms designer for `Form2`.

Comment: @wablab: That's the way to go. Closes the form and everything. Do they really need to call .Dispose() in the example?

Comment: If this applies to you, you should call dispose.  (or wrap the form in a using) : The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

Comment: Since the scope of the `testDialog` variable is within the `ShowMyDialog` method, and since it's initialized with a `new Form2()` on every call to `ShowMyDialog`, I think it's a good idea to go ahead and call `testDialog.Dispose()` at the end of the method.  Also, what @Dave said. :)