# Dialog box with text entry

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do (create a dialog box type popup which returns text as well as a yes or no response) has already been asked here:

[Messagebox with input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797774/messagebox-with-input-field)

however VS doesn't seem to recognise the answer given of using:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text");
```

Has this been removed? is there something else I can do that will give the same effect?

Comment: Did you add the reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` under Project References?

Comment: no works fine - but your code doesnt show you capturing the value to a variable..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes I did

Comment: @BugFinder are you saying something like var MyVariable Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text"); should work? because this isn't recognised either

Comment: well you'd need an = in there for starters what is "not recognized" ?

Comment: What's exactly "not recognized"? Please post the exact error message

Comment: Works fine for me (in VS2015 after adding the assembly reference), you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: type or namespace name 'Interaction' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic

Comment: @AndrewNeate that error message means you did not add the reference properly

Comment: @UnholySheep yeah sorry I thought adding references meant having "using microsoft.visualbasic" at top of program, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have added the reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Your code should read something like

```
String answer = Micsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text");
```

If you have both these, then it should work

Comment: copied what  you have written and reference is there and still having error "type or namespace name 'Interaction' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' "

Comment: then you've somehow used the wrong "micrisoft.visualbasic" reference - open a new winform app, repeat this, see if it works

Comment: I think I've been adding the reference incorrectly, sorry for the trouble thanks for the help.