# Form.ShowDialog OK button doesn't work

Tags: c#, showdialog

In my `MainForm` I'm declaring a second form:

```
Form3_addrow testDialog;
```

I've got a button and method OnClick:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyDialogBox();
}
```

And ShowMyDialogBox() method:

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
    testDialog= new Form3_addrow(tran_in);

    DialogResult dr = testDialog.ShowDialog(this);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        testDialog.Close();
    }
    else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        testDialog.Close();
    }
}
```

When I click the button, `testDialog` is displayed, but when I click the OK button, testDialog doesn't close... the CANCEL button works though. Why doesn't my form close when I  click the OK button?

Comment: What is `Form3_addrow`? Also are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: ShowDialog will block until the dialog is closed. Can you show your dialog's code (`Form3_addrow` for OK and Cancel button click)?

Comment: What is the value stored in dr? What have you done so far to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you set OK button DialogResult to OK?

Comment: Assuming WinForms, have you made the OK button the `AcceptButton` of your other form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to setting the `DialogResult` in the button click handler would be to set the `DialogResult` on the OK button itself - in form design you can set the result to OK  (this works without needing a click handler at all for the button.)

It sounds like your cancel button already has this property set

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `DialogResult` in the button click handler on your form.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487920/winforms-acceptbutton-not-working)

EDIT: And close the form in the handler as well.  Missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: And also close the form

Comment: oh i totally forget about button ok and cancel handler definitions. Thanks!

Comment: @tencentraze but if i forget about it so why Cancel button works ?

Comment: if you set dialogresult in the ok button click, that will close the form automatically and return the dialog result

Answer (score 0):

The setters from the CLR source for `System.Windows.Forms.Form.AcceptButton` and `System.Windows.Forms.Form.CancelButton` are below.

Note that the `CancelButton` setter sets the `DialogResult` property of the specified button, while the `AcceptButton` setter doesn't.

At first review this seems to be a bug in the WinForms source code.

Code:

```
Public Sub set_AcceptButton(ByVal value As IButtonControl)
  If (Not Me.AcceptButton Is value) Then
    MyBase.Properties.SetObject(Form.PropAcceptButton, value)
    Me.UpdateDefaultButton
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub set_CancelButton(ByVal value As IButtonControl)
  MyBase.Properties.SetObject(Form.PropCancelButton, value)
  If ((Not value Is Nothing) AndAlso (value.DialogResult = DialogResult.None)) Then
    value.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have not declared the `OK button` as your dialog result, you can do this at the `Designer.cs` page of your dialog :

```
 this.AcceptButton = this.button_OK;
this.button_OK.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```